# Error with SQL Server database in Visual Studio after using LINQPad

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, linqpad

I have an SQL Server database which is being used for a MVC 4 project in VS 2010. I'm using LINQPad to run queries against my database. When I open LINQPad, I can connect to my .mdf database file and run queries as expected. When I close LINQPad, open up VS and try to view my database in server explorer the following error is shown:

[image]

I can drop the database and run the `Seed()` method via an Update-Database command from package manager as a workaround to the error, but it's a bit of a hassle to have to do it every time I connect to the database via LINQPad.

EDIT (for those who cannot see images):

> The database 'C:..... .MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Could not open new database 'C:..... .MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. An attempt to attach an auto-named database file for 'C:..... .MDF' failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Is this a common error? Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Images make life sad for those of us that have them filtered at our office :(

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you are using a visual studio 2010 db project to access SQL server 2012.

Here is the MSDN workaround

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/731860/unable-to-create-a-sql-server-2012-projects-in-visual-studio-2010

---

It seems like linqPad might be doing something to "upgrade"?  A different version of linqPad might also help.

Comment: Isn't that workaround only for people who are trying to create SQL Server 2012 projects in VS 2010? I already have VS2010 SP1 installed, and from VS I am able add SQL S2012 databases to my project. My problem is once I connect to my database with LINQPad, I cannot use my database in VS after I'm finished with LINQPad.

Comment: Yeah, I think what is happening is that LP is using 2012 drivers and VS is using 2010.  This sounds like it enables the 2012 drivers for VS so then everything will be using the same stuff.  Can't reproduce your problem so I can't test.  YMMV

Answer (score -1):

While working with corrupt Microsoft SQL Server, you come across unexpected behavior of SQL Server. In order to resolve such issues of SQL Server in an efficient manner, **RecoveryFIX for SQL** Database Recovery is one such proficient third party tool. By using this tool, you can easily recover your lost, corrupt or inaccessible SQL database files from all the versions of the corrupt Microsoft SQL server.

Thanks